# How to update table avoiding duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update table avoiding duplicate data

Here in below query i am using order details table

```
    /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT [OrderDetailID]
      ,[TerminalID]
      ,[OrderType]
      ,[ConveyanceName]
      ,[TripNumber]
      ,[OrderNumber]
      ,[ConveyanceID]
      ,[TripId]
  FROM [TAMS].[OrderDetail]
```

[image]

This has ConveyanceName, TripNumber, ConveyanceId and TripId

I have conveyance Details in Conveyance Table

```
SELECT  [ConveyanceID]
      ,[ConveyanceName]
      ,[CreatedUserID]
      ,[CreatedDateTime]
      ,[LastModifiedUserID]
      ,[LastModifiedDatetime]
      ,[OldConveyanceName]
  FROM [TAMSdev].[TAMS].[Conveyance]
```

[image]

Now I want to update order details table (ConveyanceId, TripId).

But i tried something as below. But i am getting duplicate rows. Please suggest how can i do this

```
  UPDATE OD
  SET OD.ConveyanceID = C.ConveyanceID
  FROM TAMS.OrderDetail OD
  INNER JOIN TAMS.Conveyance C ON C.ConveyanceName = OD.ConveyanceName
```

Comment: What do you mean as duplicates? Your update fails with unique constraint exception?

Comment: images are not very useful to allow us to try to replicate your data and query. If you scripted a small temp table with sample data instead, we could reproduce your problem with minimal effort. Personally, i don't want to sift through the images to work out how to reproduce your problem from scratch.

Comment: Can the same `ConveyanceName` occur more than once in `Conveyance`? If it does, how do you decide which ID to use?

Comment: @DavidHedlund Yes there are multiple conveyanceName in Order details table. So I need to go and find id for that in ConveyanceTable and update with found ID on order details in conveyance ID column

Comment: Yes, but can the same `ConveyanceName` occur more than once in `Conveyance`? And if it does, how do you decide which ID to use (in `OrderDetail`)?

Comment: @DavidHedlund No. There can be multiple conveyanceNames in Orderdetails table. But conveyance Table has only one unique conveyancename. So here all i want to do is I need to join with conveyancename and update order details table with conveyanceId based on conveyancename

Comment: So what are "duplicate rows" then? 1) "Yes there are multiple conveyanceName in Order details table. So I need to go and find id for that in ConveyanceTable and update with found ID" - ok, 2) "conveyance Table has only one unique conveyancename" - ok
Where are those duplicates you are getting here?

Comment: @IvanStarostin There can be multiple conveyanceNames in Orderdetails table. But conveyance Table has only one unique conveyancename. So here all i want to do is I need to join with conveyancename and update order details table with conveyanceId based on conveyancename

Comment: @user1030181 yes, you posted that update in your question. "But i am getting duplicate rows" - what do you call duplicates? What kind of troubles are you getting executing your update script?